# matching given time with current time in java script

Tags: javascript, forms, time, compare

I want to make a reservation page where given time should be compares with current time and if reservation time is lesser than current time it shows and alert that the reservation time should be greater than current time .
  my code is as under

html:

```
<form name="addform">
 Reservation Time : <input type="time" name="restime" required />
</form>
```

java script :

```
<script>
var valid=true;
var f=document.addform;
var d = new Date();
var curr_hour = d.getHours();
var curr_min = d.getMinutes(); 
var curtime=curr_hour + ":" + curr_min;

var t=f.restime.value;
var h = t.getHours();
var m = t.getMinutes();
var rtime=h + ":" + m;

function validate(curtime,rtime){
  var currtime=Date.parse('2016-01-16'+curtime);
  var bookingtime=Date.parse('2016-01-16'+rtime);
  alert(bookingtime);
  if(bookingtime=='NaN')
  {
    alert('invalid booking time');
    valid=false;
  }
  if (bookingtime<currrtime)
  {
    alert('Your given time is lesser than current time ');
    valid=false;
  }                     
}
validate(curtime,rtime);
return valid;
</script>
```

but code doesn't showing any alert

Comment: Take a look at the console, there might be an error message waiting for you.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to compare given time and js time in unix timestamp format, view Ex. http://www.unixtimestamp.com/

In javascript you can easily get timestamp with code below:

`var timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);`

And then compare:

```
var giventime = 1453048365;
if(timestamp > giventime) alert(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem with this code

`var x = document.getElementById("restime");`
`var t=x.value;`

`function validate(curtime,t1)`
`{`
`if (t<curtime)`
`{`
`alert('Your given time is lesser than current time ');`
`valid=false;`
`}`
`}`

`validate(curtime,t);`